# Delete a market's data with multiple markets in 1 data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-management

What I need is a way of checking my df to see if I have enough data to run some functions.  I would like to know how to delete an entire "market" if there is not enough data for that particular market.  For example, I would like to delete ALL of AD3 because I only have 2 complete lines of data when I require 4. In my real case I am looking to delete any market with less than 23 lines of data and I have 100+ markets.

Here is the `dput()` of a small bit off my data.

```
data<-structure(list(market = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AD1", "AD2", "AD3"), class = "factor"), 
date = structure(c(15623, 15624, 15625, 15628, 15623, 15624, 
15625, 15628, 15625, 15628), class = "Date"), open = c(101.52, 
101.68, 102.1, 101.99, 100.73, 100.85, 101.57, 101.01, 100.56, 
100.42), high = c(102.07, 102.39, 102.36, 102.07, 101.4, 
101.59, 101.62, 101.35, 100.56, 100.71), low = c(101.26, 
101.56, 101.63, 101.5, 100.59, 100.85, 101.07, 100.97, 100.56, 
100.41), last = c(101.78, 102.08, 101.76, 101.91, 101.08, 
101.37, 101.06, 101.21, 100.41, 100.56)), .Names = c("market", 
"date", "open", "high", "low", "last"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(9:10,.Names = c("9", 
"10"), class = "omit"))
```

My 100+ markets are in 1 data frame.  So if I have 22 lines of data I need to delete all 22 lines associated with that particular "market" name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table` to count the occurrences of each market, and it's pretty simple from there:

```
min_data_points <- 4
market_tab <- table(data$market)
markets_to_keep <- names(market_tab)[market_tab >= min_data_points]

fixed_data <- subset(data, market %in% markets_to_keep)
```

Comment: Thank you, new to r and programming

Answer (score 2):

@Marius was faster, still my solution is almost identical:

```
N <- 3 # threshold
range <- names(which(table(data$market)>=N))
ans1 <- data[data$market %in% range,]
ans1
```

However, if you are to analyze 100+ markets on large data set, you'd better using `data.table` for speed up:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data)
setkey(dt, market)
ans2 <- dt[J(range)]
ans2
```

Results are similar:

```
all.equal(ans1,ans2,check.attributes=F)
# [1] TRUE
```